# Why does makefile recompiles everything when a headerfile is changed?

Tags: c, makefile

My makefile recompiles everything when a headerfile is changed, how can I make it only recompile needed files? a_functions.c uses a.h for instance.

Whenever I change a .c file the makefile only recompiles that file to an object.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
OBJECTS=main.o a_functions.o b_functions.o c_functions.o d_functions.o
DEPS=main.h a.h b.h c.h d.h
PROGRAM_NAME=program1
INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/bin

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: all
all: $(PROGRAM_NAME)

$(PROGRAM_NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(PROGRAM_NAME)

.PHONY: install
install: $(PROGRAM_NAME)
    install -c $(PROGRAM_NAME) $(INSTALL_PATH)/

.PHONY: uninstall
uninstall:
    rm -v $(INSTALL_PATH)/$(PROGRAM_NAME)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -v $(PROGRAM_NAME) *.o
```

If I change a headerfile below happens

```
$ make
gcc -c -Wall main.c -o main.o
gcc -c -Wall a_functions.c -o a_functions.o
gcc -c -Wall b_functions.c -o b_functions.o
gcc -c -Wall c_functions.c -o c_functions.o
gcc -c -Wall d_functions.c -o d_functions.o
gcc main.o a_functions.o b_functions.o c_functions.o d_functions.o -o program1
```

When I change a .c file this happens which is what I would like for all headers too.

```
$ make
gcc -c -Wall a_functions.c -o a_functions.o
gcc main.o a_functions.o b_functions.o c_functions.o d_functions.o -o program1
```

Is it common practice to want it to be this way? How would I change my code to fix the issue?

Comment: `DEPS=main.h a.h b.h c.h d.h` and then `%.o: %.c $(DEPS)`
Does it give you any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rule that says that all .o files built from .c files also depend on the contents of `$(DEPS)`

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

which appears to contain all your .h files.

```
DEPS=main.h a.h b.h c.h d.h
```

You should remove `$(DEPS)` from that rule and specify the dependencies specifically for each .o file, something like the following:

```
a_functions.o: a.h
main.o: a.h b.h
```

If you've got it installed you can use `makedepend` to do the "heavy lifting" and work out the dependencies for you and update your Makefile. And even add it as a rule like this

```
depend:
    makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(SRCS)
```

(which would need you to define what source files you have)

Comment: If your project is large enough to warrant the extra effort, there are much better ways of managing prerequisites than `makedepend`.  But they do require some complication in the makefile and a compiler that has enough capabilities (but, both gcc and clang can do this).  If you're interested see for example http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/